# KendoUI Grid - Select text on cell focus

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

The cell content selection works successfully for a numeric text box (internally handled as a Kendo NumericTextBox control) but for some reason, it doesn't work with a plain textbox column. Attached is the jsfiddle demo'ing the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/latenightcoder/TrJVK/86

This is the code in the grid setup that's of importance:

```
edit: function (e) {
        var input = e.container.find("input");
        input.focus(function (e) {
            console.log('focus');
            setTimeout(function () {
                input.select();
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the focus event was getting fired before I could even wire up the focus event handler. So this was the optimal solution to support all types of fields within the grid row:

```
        var input = e.container.find("input");
        setTimeout(function () {
            input.select();
        }, 25);
```

The modified jsfiddle can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/latenightcoder/TrJVK/90

Answer (score 0):

You're only attaching the focus event handler to it, but you're not actually telling it to focus. The question should be, why does the kendo number box do it?  :-)
Also, setTimeout's 2nd argument isn't optional (according to spec).

Try the following (http://jsfiddle.net/TrJVK/87/)

```
    edit: function (e) {
        var input = e.container.find("input");
        input.focus(function (e) {
            // var input = $(this);
            console.log('focus');
            input.select();
        });
        input.focus();
    },
```

One more note:

For future jQuery compatibility, it might be best to do the following even:

```
    edit: function (e) {
        var input = e.container.find("input");
        input.on('focus', function (e) {
            // var input = $(this);
            console.log('focus');
            input.select();
        });
        input.trigger('focus');
    },
```

Comment: The focus event is fired internally, which is why it works for the Kendo Numeric Textbox. I figured the issue was that with the regular textbox, while the focus event handler is being hooked up, the focus event has already been fired.